# how do u properly use observability and tracing with microservices, using micrometer NOT sleuth?

Tags: spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer, observability, micrometer-tracing

I'm making a simple microservices project/application with spring boot 3 and you are supposed to now use micrometer for tracing, logging, and monitoring. And guides on this really don't show this implemented in a microservices environment with a gateway, service registry, and services. So are you supposed to use different dependency's and configurations if your microservice is a consumer, producer, consumer and producer, gateway, or service registry?  Or does the the observability, tracing, and logging its all the same dependencies and configurations in each? can someone shed some light to me thank you

Answer (score 1):

Check the Boot docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.observability

The Spring portfolio is instrumented using Micrometer so you don't really need to do much for making Spring Projects observable, [here's an example with Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=prometheus,distributed-tracing,zipkin), you can find a bunch of samples in [micrometer-samples](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer-samples) and there is a project consist of 3(+2) services called [tea-service](https://github.com/jonatan-ivanov/teahouse) we use on conference demos.

Comment: didn't know that tea service existed. Thank you that's a great example for me.

Comment: You can see it in action in our SpringOne Essentials talk: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2JRrsc1who and other talks available on youtube by Marcin Grzejszczak or me: hints: https://toomuchcoding.com/talks/ or https://develotters.com/talks/